# Use white space for thousand separator

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, separator

I want to create a format for NumericTextBox for numbers like “1 000 000,00”.
I use Kendo with ASP.NET MVC and I don’t understand how change thousand separator like comma to a white space.
There is my code for specific class in javascript.

Code: strong text

```
$("#XXXXXX").kendoNumericTextBox({
        format: "#&nbsp#",      
        decimals: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 9999,
        spinners: false,
        value: XXXXXXXX
    }).addClass("nombre").attr('maxlength', '4');
```

I hope that you can help me.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decimal separator and the group separator come from the current kendo culture and they can not be set directly to the `kendoNumericTextBox` as options. However you can change the corresponding culture values, but be careful because this may affect other kendo widgets too.

Here is an example:

```
// Setting the string that separates the number groups
kendo.cultures.current.numberFormat[","] = ' ';

// Setting the string that separates a number from the fractional point    
kendo.cultures.current.numberFormat["."] = ',';

$('#myInput').kendoNumericTextBox();
```

And here is a [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9eo843cx/)

Note: you can create custom kendo culture and pass it the kendo numeric by name - `$('#input').kendoNumericTextBox({ culture: 'custom' });`

Comment: Hello, i tried your solution but i can't use kendo.cultures.numberofrmat , because I don't have this file in my kendo package. 
I create a custom culture and import it but the white space doesn't work.
Do you know an another solution?

Comment: @RomannVEGUER There is nothing in seprated file. `kendo.core` has a default culture defined. Just type this somewhere in your JavaScript `kendo.cultures.current.numberFormat[","] = ' ';`.  Please note that it's not kendo.cultures.numberofrmat but kendo.cultures.**current**.numberofrmat.

Comment: Thank you guy, it works. You save my life, it was 3 days that i search a solution ^^.

Comment: @RomannVEGUER You're welcome. You can accept the answer if it was helpful to you.